# What do I need to buy for this turntable to work in UK?

Tags: uk, electronic-items

The American prongs come off, and I assume this means I can buy a British version. Where would I find such a thing? What’s it called? Any advice is welcome thank you[image]

Comment: In theory yes, in practice, these sort of things aren't normally widely available to consumers. Normally the original product either comes with the whole set (which people then bin what they don't need) or the manufacture bags up the requisite connector for each region. You may find it easier just to put a new power supply with matching characteristics (12 V 2A) and connector.

Comment: Looks like the power supply was made to accept different plugs, so perhaps there is (or was) a plug adapter for UK use. You might contact Audio-Technica in the US and ask them. See: https://www.audio-technica.com/en-us/contact

Comment: Since the adapter itself would handle a UK input voltage (240V) you could also use a UK visitor travel adapter plug  ([like this](https://www.dunelm.com/product/twin-pack-uk-visitor-adaptors-1000088484?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIh92P7I3u6wIVS-3tCh2NTQpzEAAYAyAAEgLWtPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds))

Comment: @motosubatsu that's an answer, i think

Comment: If you want a UK-compatible adaptor, you can contact them in the UK. https://www.audio-technica.com/en-gb/contact

Comment: I suspect that a design like that with removable pins would be illegal under UK electrical consumer regulations, because you could plug in just the removable part and have exposed "live" terminals.

Comment: Expect them to sell you a whole PSU though, not just the plastic clippy bit.  Or you could pick up any 12V wall-wart PSU capable of supplying 2A - the downside here is if the appliance-end uses a standard or a whacky/proprietary connector.

Comment: @CMaster _with matching characteristics (12 V 2A) and connector_ **including connector polarity** (in the photo, the symbol below "0.6A Max" shows centre positive)

Comment: Important note, pateksan. 
@alephzero I have bought several devices in the UK which come with a similar system.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be related to travel within the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: This is a switching power supply which can work with USA & UK (I would surmise most) supplies. The only issue is the physical adapter. You can buy a separate adapter (not converter) as mentioned. I am surprised that the device did not come with some other adapters.

Answer (score 31):

Unfortunately the removable prongs are specific to this adapter. They're not the same as the removable prongs on a different adapter. So good luck finding the right ones. Perhaps there were a bunch of different prongs in the box when you bought it, and you threw the other ones away. Perhaps they put the right one on at the factory.

However, it *is* labeled 100-240V 50/60Hz. This adapter will have no trouble running on British electricity... if you can get the right prongs on it.

You are looking for an adapter which lets you plug a US plug into a British socket. It doesn't have to change the voltage, it just has to change the prongs. Something like [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-368-Go-Travel-Adaptor-white/dp/B0006OFKNC) (a random Google result; I am not endorsing this particular product):

[image: US to UK power adapter]

Note: Be careful when plugging things into this adapter, because UK and US electricity *are different* and this will give you UK electricity with US prongs. This turntable can handle both, but some appliances can't!

Comment: Worth noting you can buy an adapter like this for _super_ cheap on Amazon. Typically you'd get a pack of them for all the popular countries. Always handy to have around.

Comment: @user91988: UK outlets can supply more current than those of many other countries.  Consequently, proper UK plugs include fuses.  The cheap adapters on Amazon and eBay may not all be as bad as the scary ones featured on various YouTube channels, but spending a few extra pounds to buy something that meets safety standards seems wiser than using something made by an essentially-anonymous manufacturer.

Comment: @supercat I know you say that, but I also haven't had any problems. Maybe I like to live on the edge, I dunno.

Comment: Can also buy adapters in almost any airport.  Not super cheap, but convenient.

Comment: The example in the photo DOES state "fused" on it.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs: Is that one of the ones that is sold for "super cheap" on Amazon?  While there are no doubt many units on Amazon inexpensive which, while inexpensive, are nonetheless of reasonable quantity, there are also some that are dangerously shoddy, and I would not expect that the OP would be able to reliably tell the difference.

Comment: @supercat I don't know the source of that image

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs: It probably isn't one of the cheap ones alluded to by user91988.  Many if not most cheap adapters have no kind of fusing whatsoever, and have no trustworthy indication of how much current they could supply without overheating, melting, and shorting, or whether their plastics are sufficiently flame retardant to prevent such shorts from starting a fire before the upstream 30A mains fuse blows.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to buy a replacement power supply which has the correct output voltage, polarity & connector and can handle a 2A current draw. Amazon sell plenty of 12v 2A power supplies such as this **example** https://www.amazon.co.uk/JnDeeTM-Quality-ADAPTER-Transformer-TRANSFORMER/dp/B00ENZUQO8

All of this information is marked on your existing adapter, notice:

- OUTPUT 12V 2000mA
- [image: DC power symbol] DC power
- [image: centre positive polarity symbol] centre positive

What isn't marked is the plug diameter.

Comment: You need to ensure the connector on the other end is the same as well.

Comment: OP might choose to cut the end off the existing PSU and refit it to the new PSU, with solder and heatshrink. That's a workaround, and the only dangers are burn and possibly flipping the polarity by accident.

Comment: Added connector to the list of requirements.

Comment: There are so-called "universal" chargers/power supplies which come with a variety of connectors. You still have to ensure that it supports your voltage, power, and connector.